# Plotting datetime

Tags: datetime, seaborn

I am working with a dataset with datetime `end_date` and number `trip_length`.

```
data = {'end_date': '2015-02-19 15:46:00', 'trip_length': 300}`)
data['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['end_date'])`
data['end_just_date'] = data.end_date.dt.date

import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot('end_just_date', 'trip_length', data=data)
```

I would like to render a scatterplot of `trip_length` for all the days in a given year. I created a column of just the date, but when I plot it as my x variable, I get the following error:

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Is there a way to convert the date to an integer of days based on the months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit2: there's a better way as suggested by M. Waskom:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(less_than_two_days)
g = (g.map(plt.scatter,'trip_length','end_date'))
plt.show()
```

Edit: You can plot the year, month, and day on the x-axis like this:

```
less_than_two_days['end_yyyymmdd'] = (
    less_than_two_days['end_date'].dt.year.astype(str) + 
    less_than_two_days['end_date'].dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + 
    less_than_two_days['end_date'].dt.day.astype(str).str.zfill(2))

less_than_two_days['end_yyyymmdd'] = less_than_two_days['end_yyyymmdd'].astype(int)
```

And then to label the x-axis with the dates, do:

```
ax = sns.lmplot('end_yyyymmdd', 'trip_length', data=df)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['end_date'])
```

By the way the reason this feels like a workaround is because it is: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/257

---

Old answer: It looks like your DataFrame is called `less_than_two_days`. If so you can do this to get the day of the year in its own column:

```
less_than_two_days['end_day_of_year'] = less_than_two_days['end_date'].dt.dayofyear
```

And then do your plot:

```
sns.lmplot('end_day_of_year', 'trip_length', data=less_than_two_days)
```

Comment: Yes. I didn't explain that well in my question, but the `less_than_two_days` data includes data from four years, but is a filtered dataset of trip_lengths whose total is less than 2 days. I'll change my question above to clarify that.  I made a separate column for year, month, and day, but didn't know how to plot them all at once in a row on the x axis. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks. I followed the steps, but didn't understand the error: `ValueError: First argument must be a sequence`

Comment: I see. Yes, that works. To label the axis I could then parse that back out to the date for the bins. This seems like a common enough operation that perhaps there is a datetime built-in I'm overlooking.

Comment: @SioKCronin: added example of how to label x-axis. Let me know how that works.

Comment: Ha! I like that. I was being quite purest about having the label speak directly from its data.

Comment: Haha. No you weren't. That's the way it should be. Please see my second edit for the proper way -- which I  just learned about.

Comment: Awesome. This looks great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SioKCronin: you're most welcome. You can accept this answer with the checkmark if it helped you.